# Is there any way to return a string starting at a certain index without using the library functions

Tags: c, substring, c-strings, function-definition

> `char* string = "Hello, what's up?";`

and I want to just return

> `"at's up?"`

Comment: `&string[9]` will "return" that.

Comment: there is no library function that does that either... `string+9` works

Comment: if its in a for loop can I do &str1[i]?

Comment: Of course. Why would it be any different in a loop?

Answer (score 2):

You can write a function. If the function shall not use standard C string functions then it can look for example the following way

```
char * substr( char *s, size_t pos )
{
    size_t i = 0;

    while ( i < pos && s[i] ) ++i;

    return s + i;
}
```

As C does not support function overloading then the function above can be also written like

```
char * substr( const char *s, size_t pos )
{
    size_t i = 0;

    while ( i < pos && s[i] ) ++i;

    return ( char * )( s + i );
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * substr( const char *s, size_t pos )
{
    size_t i = 0;

    while ( i < pos && s[i] ) ++i;

    return ( char * )( s + i );
}

int main(void) 
{
    char * s = "Hello, what's up?";
    
    puts( substr( s, 9 ) );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
at's up?
```

Comment: What's up with all that unneeded whitespace?

Comment: @MarcoBonelli What do you mean?

Comment: I mean `( char * )( s + i )` instead of `(char *)(s + i)`, or `puts( substr( s, 9 ) )` instead of just `puts(substr(s, 9))`, etc. Seems odd.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli No it looks very good and readable.

Answer (score 1):

If you already know the length of the string (and therefore know that going `n` characters ahead you will not go past the end), you can use `string + n` or `&string[n]`, which are equivalent ways of "skipping" the first `n` characters of the string.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char *str = "Hello!";
    
    printf("%s\n", str + 1); // ello!
    printf("%s\n", str + 3); // lo!

    char *str2 = str + 3;
    printf("%s\n", str2); // lo!
}
```

On the other hand, if you do *not* know the length of the string, you will have to make sure you don't go past the end by using a loop first. You can write a function for this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

char *skip(char *s, size_t n) {
    while (*s && n--)
        s++;
    return s;
}

int main(void) {
    char *str = "Hello!";
    
    printf("%s\n", skip(str, 1));   // ello!
    printf("%s\n", skip(str, 3));   // lo!
    printf("%s\n", skip(str, 100)); // empty line

    char *str2 = skip(str, 3);
    printf("%s\n", str2); // lo!
}
```